# Comprobacion de numero entero no funciona

Tags: java

Estoy stack con la lectura de enteros de este programa...

Al introducir la medida de un array que he dejado en NULL necesito que la variable mida solo sea aceptada en caso de ser num entero, si no ignorar este dato y tendre que volver a introducirlo hasta que teclee un entero, en principio he hecho este codigo que parece correcto, pero si meto un numero decimal el programa sigue ejecutandose y finaliza...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author cbermejo
 */
public class ProgramaDeClasesEac {

int[] classesA = null;
int[] classesB = null;
boolean noSurti = true;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProgramaDeClasesEac programa = new ProgramaDeClasesEac();
    programa.inici();

}

private void inici() {
    while (noSurti) {
        intro();
        entraMida();
        entraPosicions();
        imprimeixPosicions();
        Compara();
        Surti();
    }
}

private void intro() {
    System.out.println("Aquest programa et demana que entris la mida de dos clases A y B.\n"
            + "Despres et demanara que entris les edats dels alumnes. \n"
            + "Una vegada estiguien entrades comparara les dues clases y retornara si la classe"
            + "< B > es mes gran que la classe < A >.");
}

private void entraMida() {

    System.out.println("Digam la mida que tenen les clases A i B:");

    **int mida = 0;
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        mida = scan.nextInt();
    } else {
        scan.next();
    }**
    classesA = new int[mida];
    classesB = new int[mida];

}

private void entraPosicions() {
    System.out.println("Ara digam les edats del nens de la classe A:");

    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {

            classesA[i] = scan.nextInt();
            if (classesA[i] > 0 && classesA[i] < 21) {
                System.out.println("la posicio: " + (i + 1) + " de la clase A es: " + classesA[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("la edat esta compresa entre 1 any i 20 anys.");
                i--;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aquest no es un valor sencer");
            i--;
            scan.next();
        }
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Ara digam les edats del nens de la classe B:");
    for (int i = 0; i < classesB.length; i++) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {

            classesB[i] = scan.nextInt();
            if (classesB[i] > 0 && classesB[i] < 21) {
                System.out.println("la posicio: " + (i + 1) + " de la clase B es: " + classesB[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("la edat esta compresa entre 1 any i 20 anys.");
                i--;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Aquest no es un valor sencer");
            i--;
            scan.next();
        }
        scan.nextLine();
    }

}

private void imprimeixPosicions() {
    System.out.print("Collectio 1: \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(classesA[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("  ");
    System.out.print("Collectio 2: \n ");
    for (int i = 0; i < classesB.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(classesB[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("  ");
}

private void Compara() {
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < classesA.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < classesB.length; j++) {
            if (classesB[i] <= classesA[j]) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (contador >= 1) {
        System.out.println("No es cumpleix que la clase B te els alumnes mayors que els de la A");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Correcte els alumnes classe B son mes grans que els de la classe A");

    }

}

private void Surti() {
    System.out.println("S ha acabat el joc.");
    noSurti = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente bucle para que no se salga de él hasta introducir un número correcto:

```java
private void entraMida() {
    int mida = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Digam la mida que tenen les clases A i B:");
        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                mida = scan.nextInt();
                break;
            } else {
                scan.next();
                System.out.println("La entrada no es numérica");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fin de la entrada de datos");
        }
    } while (true);
    classesA = new int[mida];
    classesB = new int[mida];
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es no permitir salir del bucle (con el `break`) hasta tener datos válidos.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, funciona, entiendo que while evalua cieto cuando se entra un dato entero y sale del bucle, no?

Comment: No, el bucle siempre se repite (la condición es `true` siempre) y sólo sale de él cuando asignamos el valor a `mida` con el `break` que hay bajo él.

Comment: Ok entendido, gracias por la ayuda.